# BT headsets with no lag

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

I have a [Logitech H390 headset](https://www.logitech.com/en-ca/products/headsets/h390-usb-headset.981-000014.html?crid=1873) on my trashcan MP. These are quite nice for general purpose telecommuting and gaming. I find many sets *clamp* onto your head and are very uncomfortable for long use, the H390 is much softer fitting.

However, the H390 is corded, and the cord is long enough that I run over it with my chair, causing the headset to get yanked. Now it's broken - they are not terribly strong to begin with, and fall apart even if you don't yank them. So I'm looking for a BT set to avoid this particular problem.

Poking about here I see posts about sound delays in BT speakers. Is this also a problem with headsets? Is anyone out there using an entry or mid-level BT headset and can confirm/deny that they work OK and have no lag?

Comment: Bluetooth will always have some lag. Depending on what you do some milliseconds delay may already be too much. I use BT headphones and for *most* stuff (Zoom meetings, watching YouTube,...) they are fine but e.g. when I open a virtual keyboard in LogicPro the delay is unusable.

Answer (score 1):

We use those at work a don’t have any issues unless people have low batteries, or noisy interference from household appliances or 2.4 GHz congestion in WiFi. They aren’t as good as Apple radios but better than most.

Try a USB external BTLE dongle or update the firmware on the device if you continue to have disconnects and lag. That is needed for some of our Logitech units.